# Why Python import works on pycharm but not on eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, numpy, tensorflow, pycharm

I have problems with my PyCharm (it is running extremely slow) so I decided to change to eclipse. However, the import which worked in PyCharm suddenly don't work in eclipse. I am talking about numpy and tensorflow (which were appropriately installed).

Please, can anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: Did you have a virtual environment? How did you install the packages?

Comment: I'm gonna posit that Pycharm is scanning files to "index" ... and once its done, you'll be set. BTW, its important to list your OS, python version etc as these are useful for debugging

Comment: What is the error message that Eclipse is giving you?

Comment: I had installed virtual enviorment and I use Python 3.5.2 on PyCharm. 
The error is the usual: Traceback (most recent call last):
    import numpy as np...
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: need to define the same interpreter as in PyCharm. Thanks everyone anyway!